# Adding multiple ternary operations and conditions based on interpolated values in ng-class

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

This is my directive template code.

```
'<div>' +
     '{{object.classificationName}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<span ng-class="(toggle ? \'icon- 
remove-contain\' : \'icon-add-contain\') + ' ' + ({{object.valueExists}} ? \'collapsed\': \'\')" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{object.classificationId}}" ng-click="toggle = !toggle"></span>' +
'</div>'
```

I had used two ternary operations in ng-class with an empty space in between. But, it's not working. What could be the mistake?

Output:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Answer (score 3):

> Syntax Error in  (`\'icon-add-contain\') + ' ' +
>   ({{object.valueExists}} ? \'`)

Try  replace  `+ ' ' +` to `' + ' ' + '`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.valid = true;
  $scope.enabled = true;
  
});
```

```css
.blue {
    color : blue;
}
.red {
    color : red;
}

.big {
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <!--
  ng-controller - associates any HTML element with any of the 
  controllers in your module.
  -->
  <div ng-controller="myController">
  <span ng-class="(valid ? 'red' : 'blue').concat((enabled ? ' big': ''))">
        Big Red</span>
</div>
```

The ng-class parameter has to be a JavaScript expression that evaluates to a string of space-separated class names.

You can use String.prototype.concat to have such an expression (see snippet)

On a side note, I find your code a bit complicated and the use of two ternary operator is not easy to read.